# When remediation for policy is activated in Azure?

Tags: azure, terraform, azure-cli, azure-policies

We create a virtual machine that needs 2 extensions, for that we define and assign 2 customs policies, also we create and activate remediation task to make sure that all virtual machines (new ad old vms) have these 2 extensions. Everything is done with Azure CLI.

The problem is that some times, remediation is activated immediately, or not at all even after 2 hours, and sometimes compliance doesn't detect the virtual machines, sometimes yes it does. But when we activate remdiation mannually, it works without problem for all vms.

In our terraform code , remediation is activated just after creating the vms, policies definition and assignment.

What can be the cause of that? Is there a question of time to wait before executing remediation?